# Curl - login to dashboard and view url

Tags: php, curl

I have problem with curl login. I'm using craftcms url to login (SSL) ksservice.pl/admin/login

I'm using this code to do login into dasboard and to view (run) url.

```
 <?php
// Initialize cURL
$ch = curl_init('https://ksservice.pl/admin/login.js');

// Enable HTTP POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

// Use SSL 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
 // Set POST parameters
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'username=admin&password=pass!');

// Imitate classic browser's behavior - handle cookies
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// Execute 1st request
$store = curl_exec($ch);

// Set file to download
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, https://ksservice.pl/actions/hrLink/ad/fetchAllAds');

// Execute 2nd request (file download)
$content = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

cookie.txt is created and chmod 777. When I run curl.php i have only blank page. Thanks for any help

I have do this with curl and bash script and it works

```
curl -A "Mozilla/4.73 [en] (X11; U; Linux 2.2.15 i686)" \
--cookie cjar --cookie-jar cjar \
--data "loginName=admin" \
--data "password=pass" \
--data "submit=Login" \
--location "https://ksservice.pl/admin/login">/home/szukamprac/tmp.html \
curl https://ksservice.pl/actions/hrLink/ad/fetchNewAds
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a COOKIEFILE as well

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
```

Even better, use your code within a function for reusability

Comment: What's up? What are you trying to say?

Comment: sorry, I have replace your code with my and not working ;/